# Is forwarding DTO's serialized as json between two services bad practice

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, microservices

I hope this is not too off topic, but this is a real delimmer and question I have.

I need to pass a rather nested object from one backend service (`Service1`) to another service (`Service2`), where `Service2` acts as REST facade.

**Small background..**

`Service2` is what all client apps connect to using a RESTful API. `Service2` then connects to a variety of other (some legacy) services to get the data, where it is often just passed through. The communication between `Service1` and `Service2` is .net WCF, and the REST is serviced in `Service2` via asp.net webAPI.

**Back to the task/question at hand...**

A new route I have added has a result that is assembled via a few different backend calls, and finally assembled by `Service1`. `Service1` forms part of the request adds it's own information, so this DTO assembling needs to be in `Service1`. I now need to pass this to `Service2` which will then serve it up via it's REST "front end" for client app consumption.

In the past, I pass these objects via the WCF (from `Service1` to `Service2`), and then map them from the WCF proxy objects to other DTOs in `Service2` which is then served to clients as json. Now in this case, as the objects is rather complex (nested), I am thinking should I just somehow pass this as json from `Service1` to `Service2`, and then `Service2` does not map or do any deserialization, but just pass this through as the resulting json.

***Is it bad practice to just pass the json straight though like describe above?***

Should I still deserialize this in REST service, and then reform the result using it’s own DTOs which is then served as the final json? Just passing it through does fell slightly “dirty” and like a shortcut, but the alternative is (yet more) copying of the same data.

Though I would not classify what I have as Microservices, this must come up in Microservices all the time,

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: My main concern is security: do any of those DTOs include auth tokens, or are they exchanged in a side-channel (e.g. as HTTP headers)? What security context or identity does `Service1` run under when it's exchanging messages with `Service2`?

Comment: It depends on how frequently this services are used for data exchanges but inter service communication should be done with high performance / small size protocols such as protobuff/ flatbuffers etc. Moreover, security is another thing for consideration, as @Dai mentioned, since JSON is human readable, you dont want those stuff being passed around

Comment: `Service1` to `Service2` will almost always be on the same machine, or at least on the same domain behind a firewall. The use binary TCP for the WCF with Windows authentication enabled. So the JSON would be "embedded" in the WFC proxy object, though I now see WFC always seems to convert it to a string, ie if I pass this out via the REST controller, I see a string in a tool such as postman, rather than JSON. Also looking into this. The  only reason for passing the JSON is to avoid having to re map / copy into local DTOs in `Service2` (if this is even going to be possible)

Comment: it's not a bad practice at all imo, people already doing that when they implemented custom proxy or some people called it "api gateway" (of course a more simple version, a proper gateway can do a lot more things), extra serialization / de-serialization will add unnecessary overheads, and you'll need to maintain 2 versions of your DTO (imagine a case when you need to update the DTO, you'll need to do it twice)